# Вопрос был задан не совсем правильно, но верный ответ уже дан в комментарии. Как поступать?

Tags: обсуждение

Суть в шапке. Ссылка на вопрос: [PostgreSQL установить пароль пользователю без пароля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1176089/344284).

Пользователь не указал текст ошибки, однако комментатор ухватил суть и без него и сразу же дал верный ответ. С точки зрения правил, этот вопрос не совсем верен, т.к. является неполным. Однако с точки зрения здравого смысла вопрос поставлен вполне ясно и ответ имеется, хотя и в комментарии.

Вопрос: стоит ли предпринимать какие-либо действия в данном случае?

Comment: Если вы считаете, что вопрос была задан "не совсем правильно", то укажите это в комментарии или сделайте правку. Вопрос нужен базе знаний в целом, а не только ТСу, так что даже при получении верного ответа стоит привести его в должный вид

Answer (score 4):

Внесите правку в вопрос, если от этого ответ не изменится.

Comment: Комментарий не является ответом, поэтому можно править вопрос независимо от содержимого комментария

Comment: Я не знаю, какой именно текст ошибки был у пользователя, задавшего вопрос. А чтобы поправить вопрос до корректного состояния, необходимо добавить текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

У модератора раньше был инструмент превращения комментария в ответ. Не знаю как с этим обстоит сейчас, но вполне рабочий вариант - превратить комментарий в ответ.

Comment: Такого инструмента не существует в нашем арсенале :( Можно только попросить автора комментария сделать ответ.

Comment: <s>Вот наше-то время</s>На Хэшкоде участники с достаточной репутацией могли преобразовывать комментарии в ответы (и обратно тоже).